Getting issue while passing _id to find an existing item
Creating a job portal website using react and mongodb. A user logins and save the job. So a model is created to save the jobs and created Controller. Before saving a job checks if it is exist or not by passing the _id which fetched from the req.params and the userId which from the req.payload . But it doesn't checks the existingJob and creating it as a new object.
exports.savedJobsController = async (req,res) =>{
console.log("Inside Saved Jobs Controller");



const {title,salary,email,company,location,description,category,jobType,experience,vacancy,deadline} = req.body



const {id} = req.params



const userId = req.payload



console.log(user id is : ${userId} and id is ${id});



try {



    const existingJob = await savedjobs.findOne({_id:id,userId})



    console.log(exist ${existingJob});



    if(existingJob){



        res.status(406).json("Job Already Saved to Your Collection!")



    }else{



        const newJob = new savedjobs({



            title,salary,email,company,location,description,category,jobType,experience,vacancy,deadline,userId



        })



        await newJob.save()



        res.status(200).json(newJob)



        console.log(Saved job is 



            ${newJob}



            );



    }



    



} catch (error) {



    res.status(401).json(error)



    console.log(error);



}

}

Why         is         your          code          so          spaced              apart

also, the backticks in the console.log's felt away.....

There is no unwanted spaces in my code actually. It occurred when I just copied and paste it in the description box to explain my issue

And the problem is over!
